# Java - Circular Linked List - remove function not working

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm attempting to write a circular linked list in Java but my delete function is not it working.

Comment: The public T delete(int index) method isnt working, infact it returns an error when the test file is run. I have honestly no clue as to why. The other methods namely insert, get current, etc work perfectly fine.

Comment: When i run it in eclipse, i simply get java.lang.AssertionError at line 52 of the test class. Although this was provided by my professor, so i am assuming it is correct.

Comment: be more specific what are you expecting from this function and what are you getting ?

Comment: okay i will try, the class i wrote is of a circular list, when i insert elements into the linked list they are perfectly fine and it also returns the current data, etc. But when the remove method is run and this line is tested "assertTrue(l.getCurrent() == 9);" i get an assertion error.

Comment: Tim has actually pointed out to me that the function was broken, so now big red error has disappeared but replaced with a blue one. Now the error says AssertionError: expect <3> but was<2>. Any ideas?

Comment: You should try using pencil and paper, and step through the `testRemove()` method, keeping track of what your list actually looks like (ie, what are the `data` and `next` values of each item after each insert/delete method call). This will help you understand what is actually going on in your program.

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it right now, see if i can come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

```
public T delete(int index) {
    index = index%length; 
    T delete = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<length-1; i++) {
        if (index == 0) {
             delete = current.data;
             current = current.next;
             last.next = current;
             length--;
             break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return delete;
 }
```

This function is just broken. You never modify index in the for loop, but you always check whether it is equal to 0.

There are two problems - the first is you never seem to initialize current (in fact you seem to be modifying a member variable?).
The second is you are looping through but always comparing index with a constant and never modifying constant.

if index==i is more likely to be right, but that still doesn't explain what current is. I can tell you this loop is wrong. *You* need to go away. Work out what the behaviour you need from this method is, and then work out the algorithm to produce it.

Your deletion code is correct. Your "find the element to delete" code is wrong.

Comment: I tried that code, thank you first of all. But now the error has changed to AssertionError: expect <3> but was<2>. Although it is definitely one step closer. Any ideas as to why that is happening ?

Comment: I didn't change the function, I just reformatted it so it was actually readable and pointed out that it was broken. Unfortunately it's broken in a way that means that I've no idea what you wanted it to do so I can't fix it for you...

Comment: I basically want it to remove an element from the linked List and move the elements up reducing its length by 1 in the end. I am sorry i dont know why its so hard for me to explain, but in theory a circular list has its element refer back to the first one when hit next. So when i remove an element it should still work going through the flow.

Comment: Yes, that part of your code looks fine. But your actual search for the item to delete does nothing. You just scan through the list and if index is 0 delete the first item, otherwise don't delete anything.

Comment: To be honest, i understand what you are trying to convey, but i have been working on it for so long that now i am completely lost. If i dont modify index in the loop, how would i delete that element. I tried if(index ==i) but that fails as well

Comment: I've edited with a bit more...

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it right now, see if i can come up with something.